# Naming in Security Protocols: Alice, Bob and Eve

Tags: security, naming, culture

Among computer scientists and programmers, there's the common habit of naming people in the context of security protocols e.g. `Alice`, `Bob` or `Eve`. Descriptions of more elaborate attack vector sometimes refer to `Charlie` (as does this [XKCD strip](http://xkcd.com/1323/)), but is there a convention for additional participants?

Comment: Its all covered in [Alice and Bob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob).

Comment: @MichaelT: Oops, how embarrassing. I thought of "security protocol names", "protocol participant", but not the most obvious... Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Alice and Bob were the first two described in [Applied Cryptography](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471117099).  These are two people communicating and used a placeholder names.  Keeping with a convention makes it easier for people to remember what role they play in communication.

Beyond Alice and Bob, the first letter of the name typically implies the role of the individual in the communication.

C is sometimes a third person, but other times C is a **C**racker.

D is often a fourth person in communication.

E can either be a fifth person, but often E has **E**vil intent.  Eve in particular is an **Eave**dropper.

F is a sixth person... and so on.

M becomes a **M**alicious attacker (as opposed to Eve, who just wants to eavesdrop).

O is an **O**pponent, similar to M, but not necessarily malicious.

P needs to have something **P**roven and V needs to have something **V**erified.

S is for Sybil which is a book about the treatment of a woman named Sybil Dorsett who had dissociative identity disorder.  In the context of security names, Sybil is a particular type of attacker who uses many identities often in combination with a system that uses reputation.

T is **T**rusted.

W can either be a **W**arden who guards Alice and Bob or a **W**histleblower with insider information.

Further reading:

- [Alice and Bob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob) (Wikipedia)
- [Metasyntatic variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) (Wikipedia)
- [Placeholder name (computing specific)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name#Computing-specific) (Wikipedia)

Comment: Loved the placeholder page at wikipedia. Thanks for sharing.